# how to change SublimeCodeIntel key binding for Sublime Text 3 on mac?

Tags: sublimetext3, keyboard-shortcuts, sublimecodeintel

For [SublimeCodeIntel](https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel), the default key bingding as below:

- Jump to definition = <kbd>Ctrl + Click</kbd>
- Jump to definition = <kbd>Ctrl + Cmd + Alt + Up</kbd>
- Go back = <kbd>Ctrl + Cmd + Alt + Left</kbd>
- Manual Code Intelligence = <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + space</kbd>

SublimeCodeIntel default keymap:

```html
[
 { "keys": ["shift+ctrl+space"], "command": "code_intel_auto_complete" },
 { "keys": ["super+alt+ctrl+up"], "command": "goto_python_definition"},
 { "keys": ["super+ctrl+space"], "command": "back_to_python_definition"}
]
```

SublimeCodeIntel default mouse binding:

```html
[
    { "button": "button1", "modifiers": ["ctrl"], "command": "goto_python_definition", "press_command": "drag_select" }
]
```

I want to change key binding of "Go back" to <kbd>Ctrl+ Right Click</kbd>, How to make it? Anyone can help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way:

```html
[
    {
        "button": "button1", 
        "count": 1, 
        "modifiers": ["ctrl"],
        "press_command": "drag_select",
        "command": "goto_definition"
    },
    {
        "button": "button2", 
        "count": 1, 
        "modifiers": ["ctrl"],
        "command": "back_to_python_definition"
    }
]
```

Comment: @KevinRED the path: "Preferences->Package Settings->SublimeCodeIntel->Settings - User"